# "First click free" applies to only app indexation or to deep linking too?

Tags: android, deep-linking, android-app-indexing

Does "First click free" policy apply to deep linking or only to app indexation? I'm planning to only do deep linking, but upon clicking it goes to login activity of my app. And then upon successful login, it opens up the content user clicked. Is it allowed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google forces First-click-free UI to index your app because they think it does improve user experience.

AFAIK there are no rules for deeplinking, because that's just a generic way of exposing your app content through Uris, so it's entirely up to you.